# Do a groupby and a sum but keeping other column intact in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working on a Python - Pandas project.

I have this dataFrame :

[image]

I want to refine this dataframe to have one line per Name with the sum of Damage. This is ok in fact.

The real issue is that I also want to keep all columns.
Ally can only be "T", and EncId is alway the same, so it's ok to deal with it.
But for Duration and Job it's an other story.

Here I want to keep the Job if not 0, and keep the longest duration, for example.

I realy can't figure how to handle this. I miss some methodology.

Thanks in advence for your time :)

Comment: What do you want the resulting dataframe to look like? It's not obvious from the description. It sounds like you already have the sum of Damage and a Job value. What do you mean by longest duration? Job has either `0` or a `string` value.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve]. In particular please post code/text instead of pics.

Comment: You can use Pandas Groupby, but instead of `.sum()` at the end, you can do `.agg()` and pass a `dict` of aggregations you want to do. For instance, you could sort the DF by duration, then in the groupby do `.agg({'Duration': 'first'})` along with the other aggregations.

Comment: @rpanai I'm sorry. I was a little bit on a rush. I'll read this and take my time for the next one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_agg`:

```
df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False) \
       .agg({'EncId': 'first', 'Ally': 'first', 'Name': 'first',
             'Duration': 'max', 'Job': 'max', 'Damage': 'max'})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      EncId Ally          Name  Duration  Job   Damage
0  91513775    T  Naaru Segawa       203  Smn  2274680
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'EncId': [91513775, 91513775],
   'Ally': ['T', 'T'],
   'Name': ['Naaru Segawa', 'Naaru Segawa'],
   'Duration': [191, 203],
   'Job': ['0', 'Smn'],
   'Damage': [514680, 2274680]})
print(df)

# Output:
      EncId Ally          Name  Duration  Job   Damage
0  91513775    T  Naaru Segawa       191    0   514680
1  91513775    T  Naaru Segawa       203  Smn  2274680
```

Comment: Hi ! First, thanks you :) It look very promising ! Sadly I can not test it now but It look exactly like the result I want. l'll come back tomorrow morning to post a feedback.

Comment: Hello !

After a quick try, replacing 'Damage': 'max' by 'Damage': 'sum' and some types conversion, it work perfectly fine.

This was only a part of my dataFrame but with this method I've managed to process every other columns.

Thanks you !